# main cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

This error occurs in setContentView line in this code snippet:

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

I understand that in order for R.layout.main to be resolved, a file named **res/layout/main.xml** must be present.

It is present and valid (i.e. Eclipse marks it as perfect without any errors). So, what else could cause this error?

BTW, I already tried Project > Clean. The error persists.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Make sure you don't have this in your imports:

```
import android.R;
```

but:

```
import your.application.packagename.R;
```

Comment: you are king. I replaced **import android.R;** with **import com.example.ch15_1_simple_tts_demo.R;** and that cleaned all errors but introduced a new one: "The declared package "" does not match the expected package package com.example.ch15_1_simple_tts_demo". Fortunately, Eclipse is like a bike with training wheels so it suggested adding a package declaration at the beginning of the .java file. So many fine details... You would think that in the 21st century programming for android would be different than writing assembly code for the 8088.

Comment: For me I only needed to delete the "import android.R;"

Comment: That's because you were inside a class that belongs to the same package of your `R` class.

Comment: I don't have any of these statements in my app.

Comment: If I add `import com.example.AndroidHello.R;` I get error "import ... cannot be resolved". What should I do ?

Comment: In the example I said: `your.application.packagename.R`, but you have insead `your.application.packagename.YourClassName.R` which is wrong.

Answer (score 10):

Also try:
add

```
import your.application.packagename.R;
```

and run:
eclipse->project->clean..

The error should be gone.

Answer (score 2):

If this is the problem you are encountering then check at the top of your code -
you will see:

```
import android.R
```

Delete that line and and change it into

```
import (com.xx.yy)
```

Replace (com.xx.yy) with your actual package name for the class. This problem occurs mainly when you copy all the XML and Java code of another application and paste it into your new application.

This is an example of how I replaced the `android.R` packages within one of my own apps (a puzzle game):

```
package com.pir.PUZZLEGAME_NEW;

import com.pir.PUZZLEGAME_NEW.*;
import com.pir.puzzlegame_old.R;
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Delete all your import statements from the class where you are getting this error message.

Then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I changed

```
   import android.R;
```

to

```
 import your.application.packagename.R;
```

And project ->clean still the error.

But when I Run the project the error automatically gone, may be Eclipse problem.

Answer (score 1):

for me changing

```
import org.opencv.R;
```

to

```
import com.example.opencvtryagain.R;
```

solved it, where as my package name was `com.example.opencvtryagain;`

Comment: I faced same issue with my menu resource file. Thanks for saving my time

Answer (score 0):

Also, sometimes it still won't compile even after making that needed change; *but* if you go ahead and run the app, the errs will clear up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse, then

1. Delete all your import statements from the class where you are getting this error message.
2. **press CTRL + SHIFT + O** --> OR **select Source from menu and select Organize import.** This will import all the necessary classes.

Note: Since you have a local R.class file, it will import your local file instead of the android.R file.

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the following line and it worked for me.

import android.R;