# Android-Listview items background color changing when scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview

My `ListView` contains two `Textviews`. In one row  first one is for name and second one is for result. I need to change the background color of the result `TextView` according to the result. Like if pass then the result `TextView` color will be green when fails result `TextView` color will be red.I have ten rows in my `ListView`. I have tried like this

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.items, null);

        holder.imgViewLogo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgViewLogo);
        holder.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewTitle);
        holder.txtViewDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewDescription);
        holder.txtholder = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.holder1);
        holder.img = (ImageView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.temperrr);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

    ItemBean bean = (ItemBean) itemList.get(position);

    holder.imgViewLogo.setImageResource(bean.getImage());
    holder.txtViewTitle.setText(bean.getTitle());
    holder.txtViewDescription.setText(bean.getDescription());
  //------------------  
    if (position==0)
    {
        if(GridviewAdapter.glu>=81)
        {
        holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_arrow);
        holder.txtViewDescription.setBackgroundResource(R.color.resultred);  
        holder.txtholder.setBackgroundResource(R.color.resultred);  
        }
        else if (GridviewAdapter.glu==79||GridviewAdapter.glu==80)
        {
            holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.orange_arrow);
            holder.txtViewDescription.setBackgroundResource(R.color.resultoren);  
            holder.txtholder.setBackgroundResource(R.color.resultoren);  
        }
        else
        {
            holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.resultarrawnocolor);
            holder.txtViewDescription.setBackgroundResource(0);  
            holder.txtholder.setBackgroundResource(0);  
        }

    }
        holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.resultarrawnocolor);
       return convertView;
}
```

But, when scrolling the list the another random  items's background color changing.what I have to do .? How can I control the items at each position in the listview . The above code is for just for the first row. am I right?

Comment: use android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" in ur urlistview.xml file

Comment: what is `GridviewAdapter.glu` ? where r u storing the marks?r the marks displayed in any textview? it will be easy to help if u can post whole class or if u describe what u r doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
     @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.items, null);

            holder.imgViewLogo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgViewLogo);
            holder.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewTitle);
            holder.txtViewDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewDescription);
            holder.txtholder = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.holder1);
            holder.img = (ImageView)  convertView.findViewById(R.id.temperrr);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();




        ItemBean bean = (ItemBean) itemList.get(position);

        holder.imgViewLogo.setImageResource(bean.getImage());
        holder.txtViewTitle.setText(bean.getTitle());
        holder.txtViewDescription.setText(bean.getDescription());


//**********SET ALSO YOUR DEFAULT BACKGROUND HERE******** like//

     holder.txtViewDescription.setBackgroundResource(R.color.DEFAULCOLOR);  
     holder.txtholder.setBackgroundResource(R.color.DEFAULCOLOR); 
     holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.defalut_image);


//**********SET ALSO YOUR DEFAULT BACKGROUND HERE******** ok//


      //------------------  
        if (position==0)
        {
            if(GridviewAdapter.glu>=81)
            {
            holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_arrow);
            holder.txtViewDescription.setBackgroundResource(R.color.resultred);  
            holder.txtholder.setBackgroundResource(R.color.resultred);  
            }
            else if (GridviewAdapter.glu==79||GridviewAdapter.glu==80)
            {
                holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.orange_arrow);
                holder.txtViewDescription.setBackgroundResource(R.color.resultoren);  
                holder.txtholder.setBackgroundResource(R.color.resultoren);  
            }
            else
            {
                holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.resultarrawnocolor);
                holder.txtViewDescription.setBackgroundResource(0);  
                holder.txtholder.setBackgroundResource(0);  
            }

        }
            holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.resultarrawnocolor);
           return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: hey but it doesnt change the color of arrow else everything is okei.

Comment: holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.defaultImage); in the same place

Answer (score 7):

I think it is because list view recycles the view hence causing such problems .Try the following :

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = null;
        convertView = null;
        row = convertView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent,
                    false);
                       // your code 


          }
     return row;
}
```

Since convert view and row view both are intialized as null .Hence rows will be inflated every time and preventing recycling of views .

Link:
[Listview android recycling](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/)
This links explains the mechanism of recycling views.

- use the above code if wrong views are changing color.
- **if you are trying to say** on touching views while scrolling background becomes black then use the following in list view

> android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"

Comment: Hey thank you but im having a problem at this line  row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent,false);

Comment: its "rachita " not "richita "!! It will be more  helpful if you post your entire  logcat error  message ,so that everyone can see the exact error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143369/main-cannot-be-resolved-or-is-not-a-field .Check this ,it may solve your error

Comment: @Rachita you should not set the convertview to null

Comment: Y so ? please let me know will it cause any problems ?? I fixed by problem by doing this .

Comment: I think it may not give any error but it may affect the performance and also spoils the cause of having a view holder class.because we are doing so in order to avoid the costly findViewById(). more is in this [Listview Perfomance tips](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/)

Comment: ok thanks :) But I was unable to  find any better solution to this problem! Pls let me know if you find one

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the ListView recycling mechanism. Knowing it really solved my ListView adapter problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this,

```
if(Yourmark[position]<50) //Where Yourmark[] is the mark array you are passing to your custom adapter
{
        holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_arrow);
        holder.txtViewDescription.setBackgroundResource(R.color.resultred);  
        holder.txtholder.setBackgroundResource(R.color.resultred);  
}

else
{
        holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_arrow);
        holder.txtViewDescription.setBackgroundResource(R.color.resultgreen);  
        holder.txtholder.setBackgroundResource(R.color.resultgreen);  
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set this code on adapter (custom), so you can recycle the view with the previous color only if the view is selected.

```
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );

    Task task = taskArrayList.get(position);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_row, parent, false);

    if(MyActivity.getIsClicked() && MyActivity.getPositionClicked() == position){
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.backgroundSelectedItem);
    }
```