# ExpandableListView item background color weird behavior

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am trying to set background color when the user touch a child inside expandable list view. I managed to do this by using this code:

```
ArrayList<ChildView> childViewList;

ExpandableListView expandablelistview_options = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.expandablelistview_options);

expandablelistview_options.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)
{
    int index = removeChildView(groupPosition);
    ArrayList<ConciergeOptionsPairs> children=data.Options.get(groupPosition).childrens;

    if (index != childPosition)
    {
        v.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(),R.color.orange));
        v.invalidate();
        addChildView(new ChildView(groupPosition, childPosition, v, children.get(childPosition)));
    }

    return false;
}
});

private int removeChildView(int groupPosition)
    {
        int index = 0;
        int childpos = 0;
        boolean exists = false;
        for (ChildView c : childViewList)
        {
            if (c.groupPosition == groupPosition)
            {
                c.view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(),R.color.transparent));
                c.view.invalidate();
                childpos = c.childPosition;
                exists = true;
                break;
            }
            index++;
        }

        if (exists)
        {
            childViewList.remove(index);
            return childpos;
        }

        return -1;
    }

private void addChildView(ChildView child)
{
    childViewList.add(child);
}
```

Everything works fine except from this weird behavior:

I have 2 group Views, If I expand the second group, choose the second child and then expand the first group, the background of the first child of the first group get colored and the background of the child of the second group get transparent.

[image]

When I expand the first group without choosing any child :

[image]

If I collapse the first group, the background of the child of the second group get colored again.

Here is my ExpandableListView adapter code:

```
public class ConciergeOptionsExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ConciergeOptions> data;
    private HotelStay hotelStay;
    private int lastExpandedGroupPosition;

    public ConciergeOptionsExpandableListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ConciergeOptions> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        hotelStay=HotelStay.getInstance(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this.data.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ConciergeOptions options = (ConciergeOptions) getGroup(groupPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.concierge_options_item, null);
        }

        RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.container);
        TextView option_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.option_name);
        ImageView arrow = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrow);

        option_name.setText(options.name);

        if(isExpanded){
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.bluebutton);
        }else{
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.transparent);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return (this.data.get(groupPosition).childrens.size());
    }


    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        ArrayList<ConciergeOptionsPairs> children=this.data.get(groupPosition).childrens;
        if(children!=null){
            return children.get(childPosititon);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }


    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.concierge_options_inner_items, null);
        }

        TextView option_type = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.option_type);
        TextView price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        TextView decimal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.decimal);
        TextView currency = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.currency);

        ConciergeOptionsPairs option_pair = (ConciergeOptionsPairs) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        option_type.setText(option_pair.name);

        double t_price = Double.parseDouble(option_pair.value);
        double dec = t_price - (long) t_price;
        long decim = (long) dec;

        int decimal_int = (int) t_price;

        price.setText("+" + String.valueOf(decimal_int));
        decimal.setText("." + String.valueOf(decim));
        currency.setText("$");

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Any idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: so there will be only one item u want o change color?

Comment: One item for each group

Comment: problem is that when u explicitly handle any item color visibility etc are goes wrong if u don't handle it in adapter because of views recycling so in your case you have to maintain  the flag that the color for that item need to change you can set that flag in your data set and handle same in adapter using conditional statement

Comment: this will help u take an idea from it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601760/android-listview-items-background-color-changing-when-scrolling

Comment: I moved the onclick listener inside the adapter and kept the addChildView and removeChildView methods inside the fragment but I still face the same problem.

Comment: I tried both answers from the link you posted, none worked. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i consider **ConciergeOptionsPairs** as your child data so add one boolean variable **isSelect** in **ConciergeOptionsPairs** class then in your **onChildClick**

```
@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)
{

    ArrayList<ConciergeOptionsPairs> children=data.Options.get(groupPosition).childrens; //i consider this is your child view array, need to be same dataset which used as child array
    int count=0;
   for(ConciergeOptionsPairs objChild:children)
   {
      if(count==childPosition)
         objChild.isSelect=true;
      else 
       objChild.isSelect=false;
    count++;

   }

   yourexpandableadpater.notifyDataSetChanged(); 


    return false;
}
});
```

now in your **adapter** in **getChildView**

```
      @Override
        public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                                 boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.concierge_options_inner_items, null);
            }

            TextView option_type = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.option_type);
            TextView price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            TextView decimal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.decimal);
            TextView currency = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.currency);

            ConciergeOptionsPairs option_pair = (ConciergeOptionsPairs) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
            option_type.setText(option_pair.name);

            double t_price = Double.parseDouble(option_pair.value);
            double dec = t_price - (long) t_price;
            long decim = (long) dec;

            int decimal_int = (int) t_price;

            price.setText("+" + String.valueOf(decimal_int));
            decimal.setText("." + String.valueOf(decim));
            currency.setText("$");
            if(option_pair.isSelect)
convertView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.orange));
    else
convertView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.transparent));
            return convertView;
        }
```

this is what i understand your code you can check with this

Comment: welcome, because of recycling behavior  of list we need to handle views state in getview