# errors when trying client side of Google cloud messaging

Tags: android, android-layout, google-cloud-messaging

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  btnRegId = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetRegId);
  etRegId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRegId); 
  btnRegId.setOnClickListener(this);
```

I am getting this error:

```
activity_main cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

and also for `btnGetRegId` and `etRegId`.

I have `activity_main.xml` as my layout file
declarations in that are correct. Still cant be able to figure out the problem
thanks

Comment: Try post your xml code ?

Comment: Might be there are some error in your xml
Post your xml code here

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have this in your imports:

```
import android.R;
```

but:

```
import your.application.packagename.R;
```

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143369/main-cannot-be-resolved-or-is-not-a-field)