# getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);main cannot be resolved or is not a field,

Tags: android

i want to make maps. when i will try for first i have problem. this is my problem.

this my code

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

in this code, i have problem

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
```

the comment is main cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: Try to clean your project and build again..

Comment: The solution to similar problem is discussed here [main can't be resolved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143369/main-cannot-be-resolved-or-is-not-a-field)

Comment: Try changing getMenuInflater() to getSupportMenuInflater()

Comment: this error arise because you menu.xml file name is different.check menu file name and give same as your problem will solve

Answer (score 1):

You should have a menu.xml file in your res/menu folder (if you don't have any, make it), with a content like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="YOUR_MENU_ITEM"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue Just check your import for R. In my case it was.

import android.R;

Change it to

import your.application.packagename.R;