# getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu); Cannot resolve symbol 'main'

Tags: android

Hoping you can help me. I'm new to android and have been following a tutorial for music player but I'm getting this error: Cannot resolve symbol 'main' on the line getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu); (word: main). I'm so new to android and android studio.

Originally, the error was on the word 'menu' and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27199592/getmenuinflater-inflater-menu-main-menumain-cannot-be-resolved-or-is-not-a?lq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27514540/android-development-getmenuinflaterr-menu-main-menu) and I just followed it, but now I'm getting an error for the word 'main'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56XLT.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to `clean` and `rebuild` project

Comment: Please add your error code and also, the code causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`main` should match an XML file that contains the layout for the menu. It is usually in the res/menu folder. Expand that folder and you should see the menu file. By the way, it's most likely `menu_main` and not `main` So try changing `main` to `menu_main` in your code and see if the error goes away